# How to use a nested string in App.xaml static resources...?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, staticresource, app.xaml

In my App.xaml file, I have the following static resources defined...

```
<x:String x:Key="StaticString1">static string 1</x:String>
<x:String x:Key="StaticString2">static string 2 using {StaticResource StaticString1}</x:String>
```

In the content view (on another page), I want to display `StaticString2` and have it automatically pull in `StaticString1` but it isn't working.
I want it to say "static string 2 using static string 1" but instead it just shows a literal with the curly braces ("static string 2 using {StaticResource StaticString1}").

Is it possible to do this in static resources or do I need to use a `<Label.FormattedText>` with `<Span>`s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can combine two strings in the xaml.

You can use `<Label.FormattedText>` with `<Span>` as you mentiond to achieve this:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label >
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span TextColor="Black" FontSize="18" Text="{StaticResource StaticString2}"/>
                        <Span TextColor="Black" FontSize="18" Text=" "/>
                        <Span TextColor="Black" FontSize="18" Text="{StaticResource StaticString1}"/>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

And in `App.xaml`:

```
    <x:String x:Key="StaticString1">static string 1</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="StaticString2">static string 2 using </x:String>
```